# Adding legends to a pgf plot with table

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I need to add a legend to each color in the plot. Like, inserting a box inside the plot that has the color and its name:

[image: box inside the plot]

How can I do that?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            tick align=outside,
            tick pos=left,
            x grid style={darkgray176},
            xtick style={color=black},
            y grid style={darkgray176},
            ytick style={color=black},
            yticklabels={,,},
            xticklabels={,,},
            xtick align=inside,
            ytick align=inside,
            grid = none
            ]   
            \addplot [colormap/viridis, only marks, scatter, scatter src=explicit]
            table [x=x, y=y, meta=colordata]{%
                x  y  colordata
                5.1 3.5 0.0
                4.9 3 0.0
                4.7 3.2 0.0
                4.6 3.1 0.0
                5 3.6 0.0
                5.4 3.9 0.0
                4.6 3.4 0.0
                5 3.4 0.0
                4.4 2.9 0.0
                4.9 3.1 0.0
                5.4 3.7 0.0
                4.8 3.4 0.0
                4.8 3 0.0
                4.3 3 0.0
                5.8 4 0.0
                5.7 4.4 0.0
                5.4 3.9 0.0
                5.1 3.5 0.0
                5.7 3.8 0.0
                5.1 3.8 0.0
                5.4 3.4 0.0
                5.1 3.7 0.0
                4.6 3.6 0.0
                5.1 3.3 0.0
                4.8 3.4 0.0
                5 3 0.0
                5 3.4 0.0
                5.2 3.5 0.0
                5.2 3.4 0.0
                4.7 3.2 0.0
                4.8 3.1 0.0
                5.4 3.4 0.0
                5.2 4.1 0.0
                5.5 4.2 0.0
                4.9 3.1 0.0
                5 3.2 0.0
                5.5 3.5 0.0
                4.9 3.6 0.0
                4.4 3 0.0
                5.1 3.4 0.0
                5 3.5 0.0
                4.5 2.3 0.0
                4.4 3.2 0.0
                5 3.5 0.0
                5.1 3.8 0.0
                4.8 3 0.0
                5.1 3.8 0.0
                4.6 3.2 0.0
                5.3 3.7 0.0
                5 3.3 0.0
                7 3.2 1.0
                6.4 3.2 1.0
                6.9 3.1 1.0
                5.5 2.3 1.0
                6.5 2.8 1.0
                5.7 2.8 1.0
                6.3 3.3 1.0
                4.9 2.4 1.0
                6.6 2.9 1.0
                5.2 2.7 1.0
                5 2 1.0
                5.9 3 1.0
                6 2.2 1.0
                6.1 2.9 1.0
                5.6 2.9 1.0
                6.7 3.1 1.0
                5.6 3 1.0
                5.8 2.7 1.0
                6.2 2.2 1.0
                5.6 2.5 1.0
                5.9 3.2 1.0
                6.1 2.8 1.0
                6.3 2.5 1.0
                6.1 2.8 1.0
                6.4 2.9 1.0
                6.6 3 1.0
                6.8 2.8 1.0
                6.7 3 1.0
                6 2.9 1.0
                5.7 2.6 1.0
                5.5 2.4 1.0
                5.5 2.4 1.0
                5.8 2.7 1.0
                6 2.7 1.0
                5.4 3 1.0
                6 3.4 1.0
                6.7 3.1 1.0
                6.3 2.3 1.0
                5.6 3 1.0
                5.5 2.5 1.0
                5.5 2.6 1.0
                6.1 3 1.0
                5.8 2.6 1.0
                5 2.3 1.0
                5.6 2.7 1.0
                5.7 3 1.0
                5.7 2.9 1.0
                6.2 2.9 1.0
                5.1 2.5 1.0
                5.7 2.8 1.0
                6.3 3.3 2.0
                5.8 2.7 2.0
                7.1 3 2.0
                6.3 2.9 2.0
                6.5 3 2.0
                7.6 3 2.0
                4.9 2.5 2.0
                7.3 2.9 2.0
                6.7 2.5 2.0
                7.2 3.6 2.0
                6.5 3.2 2.0
                6.4 2.7 2.0
                6.8 3 2.0
                5.7 2.5 2.0
                5.8 2.8 2.0
                6.4 3.2 2.0
                6.5 3 2.0
                7.7 3.8 2.0
                7.7 2.6 2.0
                6 2.2 2.0
                6.9 3.2 2.0
                5.6 2.8 2.0
                7.7 2.8 2.0
                6.3 2.7 2.0
                6.7 3.3 2.0
                7.2 3.2 2.0
                6.2 2.8 2.0
                6.1 3 2.0
                6.4 2.8 2.0
                7.2 3 2.0
                7.4 2.8 2.0
                7.9 3.8 2.0
                6.4 2.8 2.0
                6.3 2.8 2.0
                6.1 2.6 2.0
                7.7 3 2.0
                6.3 3.4 2.0
                6.4 3.1 2.0
                6 3 2.0
                6.9 3.1 2.0
                6.7 3.1 2.0
                6.9 3.1 2.0
                5.8 2.7 2.0
                6.8 3.2 2.0
                6.7 3.3 2.0
                6.7 3 2.0
                6.3 2.5 2.0
                6.5 3 2.0
                6.2 3.4 2.0
                5.9 3 2.0
            };
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use of the fact that one can access the colors of a colormap. This is done with the

```
color of colormap=#1 of viridis
```

key, in which the argument indicates which color is used. `0` means the minimum value and `1000` the maximum. Since your meta values range from 0 to 2, this means that 0 gets mapped to 0, 1 to 500 and 2 to 1000. And then you can create the legend manually.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,shadows.blur}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[crect/.style={inner xsep=1em,inner ysep=0.5ex,
            fill,color of colormap=#1 of viridis},crect/.default=0]
        
        \definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            tick align=outside,
            tick pos=left,
            x grid style={darkgray176},
            xtick style={color=black},
            y grid style={darkgray176},
            ytick style={color=black},
            yticklabels={,,},
            xticklabels={,,},
            xtick align=inside,
            ytick align=inside,
            grid = none
            ]   
            \addplot [colormap/viridis, only marks, scatter, scatter src=explicit]
            table [x=x, y=y, meta=colordata]{%
                x  y  colordata
                5.1 3.5 0.0
                4.9 3 0.0
                4.7 3.2 0.0
                4.6 3.1 0.0
                5 3.6 0.0
                5.4 3.9 0.0
                4.6 3.4 0.0
                5 3.4 0.0
                4.4 2.9 0.0
                4.9 3.1 0.0
                5.4 3.7 0.0
                4.8 3.4 0.0
                4.8 3 0.0
                4.3 3 0.0
                5.8 4 0.0
                5.7 4.4 0.0
                5.4 3.9 0.0
                5.1 3.5 0.0
                5.7 3.8 0.0
                5.1 3.8 0.0
                5.4 3.4 0.0
                5.1 3.7 0.0
                4.6 3.6 0.0
                5.1 3.3 0.0
                4.8 3.4 0.0
                5 3 0.0
                5 3.4 0.0
                5.2 3.5 0.0
                5.2 3.4 0.0
                4.7 3.2 0.0
                4.8 3.1 0.0
                5.4 3.4 0.0
                5.2 4.1 0.0
                5.5 4.2 0.0
                4.9 3.1 0.0
                5 3.2 0.0
                5.5 3.5 0.0
                4.9 3.6 0.0
                4.4 3 0.0
                5.1 3.4 0.0
                5 3.5 0.0
                4.5 2.3 0.0
                4.4 3.2 0.0
                5 3.5 0.0
                5.1 3.8 0.0
                4.8 3 0.0
                5.1 3.8 0.0
                4.6 3.2 0.0
                5.3 3.7 0.0
                5 3.3 0.0
                7 3.2 1.0
                6.4 3.2 1.0
                6.9 3.1 1.0
                5.5 2.3 1.0
                6.5 2.8 1.0
                5.7 2.8 1.0
                6.3 3.3 1.0
                4.9 2.4 1.0
                6.6 2.9 1.0
                5.2 2.7 1.0
                5 2 1.0
                5.9 3 1.0
                6 2.2 1.0
                6.1 2.9 1.0
                5.6 2.9 1.0
                6.7 3.1 1.0
                5.6 3 1.0
                5.8 2.7 1.0
                6.2 2.2 1.0
                5.6 2.5 1.0
                5.9 3.2 1.0
                6.1 2.8 1.0
                6.3 2.5 1.0
                6.1 2.8 1.0
                6.4 2.9 1.0
                6.6 3 1.0
                6.8 2.8 1.0
                6.7 3 1.0
                6 2.9 1.0
                5.7 2.6 1.0
                5.5 2.4 1.0
                5.5 2.4 1.0
                5.8 2.7 1.0
                6 2.7 1.0
                5.4 3 1.0
                6 3.4 1.0
                6.7 3.1 1.0
                6.3 2.3 1.0
                5.6 3 1.0
                5.5 2.5 1.0
                5.5 2.6 1.0
                6.1 3 1.0
                5.8 2.6 1.0
                5 2.3 1.0
                5.6 2.7 1.0
                5.7 3 1.0
                5.7 2.9 1.0
                6.2 2.9 1.0
                5.1 2.5 1.0
                5.7 2.8 1.0
                6.3 3.3 2.0
                5.8 2.7 2.0
                7.1 3 2.0
                6.3 2.9 2.0
                6.5 3 2.0
                7.6 3 2.0
                4.9 2.5 2.0
                7.3 2.9 2.0
                6.7 2.5 2.0
                7.2 3.6 2.0
                6.5 3.2 2.0
                6.4 2.7 2.0
                6.8 3 2.0
                5.7 2.5 2.0
                5.8 2.8 2.0
                6.4 3.2 2.0
                6.5 3 2.0
                7.7 3.8 2.0
                7.7 2.6 2.0
                6 2.2 2.0
                6.9 3.2 2.0
                5.6 2.8 2.0
                7.7 2.8 2.0
                6.3 2.7 2.0
                6.7 3.3 2.0
                7.2 3.2 2.0
                6.2 2.8 2.0
                6.1 3 2.0
                6.4 2.8 2.0
                7.2 3 2.0
                7.4 2.8 2.0
                7.9 3.8 2.0
                6.4 2.8 2.0
                6.3 2.8 2.0
                6.1 2.6 2.0
                7.7 3 2.0
                6.3 3.4 2.0
                6.4 3.1 2.0
                6 3 2.0
                6.9 3.1 2.0
                6.7 3.1 2.0
                6.9 3.1 2.0
                5.8 2.7 2.0
                6.8 3.2 2.0
                6.7 3.3 2.0
                6.7 3 2.0
                6.3 2.5 2.0
                6.5 3 2.0
                6.2 3.4 2.0
                5.9 3 2.0
            };
            
        \end{axis}
        \matrix[matrix of nodes,matrix anchor=north east,
            cells={nodes={anchor=west,sharp corners}},
            fill=white,rounded corners,blur shadow] 
            at ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-1ex]current axis.north east)
            {   
                |[crect=0]| & some entry \\
                |[crect=500]| & another entry \\
                |[crect=1000]| & new entry \\
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]